# Use JPA AttributeConverter to convert class into Geometry

Tags: java, hibernate, postgis, converters

I have a class (PointAreaModel) which encapsulates some geographical information and I want to use it as an attribute in a JPA entity with Hibernate 5.2 spatial and postgres with postgis.
In order to keep same logic used in other places of my code, I wanted to use an AttributeConverter (PointAreaModelConverter) to save the geometry attribute of the class.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public  class PointAreaModelConverter implements AttributeConverter<PointAreaModel, Point> {
    public PointAreaModelConverter() {
    }
    @Override
    public Point convertToDatabaseColumn(PointAreaModel attribute) {
        return (attribute != null) ? (Point)(attribute.getAreaGeometry()) : null;
    }
    @Override
    public PointAreaModel convertToEntityAttribute(Point dbData) {
        return (dbData != null) ? new PointAreaModel(dbData.getX(),dbData.getY()) : null;
    }
}
```

My entity has this field:

```
private PointAreaModel targetCenteredPoint;
```

The class is:

```
public class PointAreaModel implements AreaModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final AreaType areaType = AreaType.POINT;
    
    private LatLonPoint areaDefinition;
    private Geometry areaGeometry;


    /** Constructors */

    public PointAreaModel() {}
    
    public PointAreaModel(double lat, double lon) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.areaDefinition = new LatLonPoint(lat, lon);
        this.setAreaGeometry();
    }

    /** */

    /** Getters and setters */
    

    @Override
    public AreaType getAreaType() {
        return areaType;
    }

    @Override
    public LatLonPoint getAreaDefinition() {
        return areaDefinition;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAreaDefinition (Serializable areaDefinition) {
        this.areaDefinition = (LatLonPoint) areaDefinition;
        this.setAreaGeometry();
    }

    @Override
    public Geometry getAreaGeometry() {
        return areaGeometry;
    }

    private void setAreaGeometry () {
        GeometryFactory gf=new GeometryFactory();
        areaGeometry=gf.createPoint(areaDefinition.getLonLatCoordinate());
        areaGeometry.setSRID(4326);
    }
    
}
```

but it fails with error:
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1178270318

If I search for this code in the console log I also find:

*

> Could not find matching scoped JavaTypeDescriptor for requested Java
> class [it.egeos.cut3g.cskcsgadapter.common.areamodels.PointAreaModel];
> falling back to static registry 00:08:01.303 DEBUG
> (RegistryHelper.java:56) Using  cached JavaTypeDescriptor instance for
> Java class [org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point] 00:08:01.304 DEBUG
> (JdbcTypeJavaClassMappings.java:65) JDBC type code mapping not known
> for class [org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry]; using custom code
> [1178270318]

- 

Strangely I can use Point or Geometry as datatype on private fields of my entities without any issue. This problem seems to be related only to converter. Hibernate seems to fail to recognize postgis types when using the converter.
Obviously I've set the proper dialect (Postgis) since it works properly everywhere but in the converter.
I've also tried to change Point into Geometry with the same result. If I change Point to String everything works well.

Last attempt was to add explicit column definition in my entity:

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry")
```

In this case the application starts, the schema is correctly generated, but when an insert is attempted, an error message come out:

*

> 00:45:09.387 DEBUG
> (AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:87) Converted value
> on binding :
> it.egeos.cut3g.cskcsgadapter.common.areamodels.PointAreaModel@17d606c9
> -> POINT (1 2) 00:45:09.388 TRACE (BasicBinder.java:64) binding parameter [5] as [VARBINARY] - [POINT (1 2)] 00:45:09.391 INFO
> (AbstractBatchImpl.java:208) HHH000010: On release of batch it still
> contained JDBC statements 00:45:09.394 INFO
> (ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener.java:136)  Error starting
> ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your
> application with 'debug' enabled. 00:45:09.413 ERROR
> (SpringApplication.java:856) Application run failed
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:807)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:788)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1309)
> at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1298)
> at
> it.egeos.cut3g.cskcsgadapter.feasibility.Application.main(Application.java:33)
> Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown
> unwrap conversion requested: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry to [B;
> nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unknown unwrap
> conversion requested: org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry to [B    at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
> at
> org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)

- 

Anyone can help me trying to find a solution?
Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1:
I found this reference https://gitter.im/hibernate/hibernate-orm?at=5ab11305e4d1c636041f1251
If you search for "dialect" you see a similar question. Answer seems to be that converters don't support geometry types. Maybe it will be possible with Hibernate 6. Someones has any other suggestions?